# Missing last token in Capital Cashino

Tags: yooka-laylee

I'm missing one final token to finish the Capital Cashino requirements, but I've scoured the entire map. Where might I be able to find a single token?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're likely missing the single token either:

- **Atop the golf course's flagstick**
- **Beneath the short ramp used to enter the house of cards** (be sure to turn the camera angle—I missed it several times)

Barring that, there are more single tokens on the roulette tables. If you are missing a bunch, make sure you have opened all broken (blue) slot machines and run the errands for all four pigs.

Comment: Still missing one after the one under the ramp... I got the flagpole one already.

Comment: @TimmyJim, double-check underneath the ramp (rotate the camera) and transform (helicopter) before talking to the pigs. They have a bunch. Otherwise looks like you'll be doubling back to each of the token groups to double-check.

Comment: Discovered the helicopter part with pigs like 10 seconds after posting.  Still missing 1 token though... and 4 quills >:(  Definitely got the ramp coin though